# Android how to wait for coordinates calculation completed?

Tags: android, android-activity, measurement, measure

I have an Android application that create all the layout programmatically in the onCreate method, after that I need to do some calculation on the coordinates of some of the views I created, but when I try to get coordinates on screen, it always return 0,0.
I think that may be caused from the fact that the activity is still not rendered as in fact by debugging I still see a grey screen if i place a breakpoint on the point where I get coordinates, how can I calculate coordinates after starting activity?
For me it's ok even if it's out of onCreate, I just need it to be executed after that the activity rendering, and if possible I'd like to not use a OnGlobalLayoutListener (if there's no other way well... i'll just get used to the idea, but i'd like to know if there's some other way).
Ah, I even tried to put it on the onResume, but it doesn't work, probably when onResume is called the rendering is still not finished.

Comment: You're likely trying to access components of the layout before they are inflated. We can't really know unless you post some code. At least show us the onCreate stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extends View class and writing your own `protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {` could help you.

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    final float yCenterX = w / 2;
    final float yCenterY = h / 2;
    ...
}
```